# What is the difference between 'decrease' and 'reduce' in the context set out below?

Tags: meaning

While walking at a brisk pace with a friend, I said we should "reduce our pace", but immediately corrected myself to "decrease our pace". I then went back and forth, not being able to decide which one is correct. Could you guys please help me decide? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As they are both synonyms of each other the difference in use can be very subtle.

*"reduce our pace"* can mean to walk slower but it can also mean to lessen the length of stride.

*"decrease our pace"* seems to refer more to how fast you are walking. It could also relate to stride but in this case suggests that fewer strides are taken, ergo walk slower.

My personal preference is to view *Reduce* as something that I do and *Decrease* as something that is done despite me.

*I will reduce company costs by half.

Company costs will decrease by half.*

Answer (score 2):

Both verbs are Latin. Both verbs can be used with reference to number.

The sense of to re-duce is to make something smaller in number. Latin re- here means back. And the word element -duce from Latin ducere means to draw something or to lead someone somewhere.

The sense of to decrease is to become smaller in number. The word element -crease
is from Latin crescere meaning to grow said of plants, human beings and figuratively of things. The Latin prefix de- here marks the contrary of to grow, to become smaller.

I think this is the difference originally. Nonetheless you will find instances where "to decrease" is used instead of "to reduce",  obviously because the meaning of Latin ducere and crescere is not clear to those who have no knowledge of Latin.

So Oxford Concise English gives as definition of "to decrease" make or become smaller or fewer, that is, "to decrease" is used interchangeably for "to reduce".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use both interchangeably.
As for the difference between the two, I think *reduce* is a verb,
while *decrease* can be both a noun and a verb.

*eg* the pace was decreased instead of the pace was reduced

That's the difference and similarities I see but I wouldn't bet the farm on it though..